# Only last row of Entries is cleared when reset function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I'm practicing basic concepts of python and trying to program the 'SUDOKU' game with the help of Tkinter. But the program is conflicting when I'm trying to clear all the Entry fields using the reset function because only the Entries at last row are executed except the whole 2D list.

```
def reset():
    for i in range(0,rows,1):
        for j in range(0,cols,1):
            col[i][j].delete(0, "end")

from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Button, CENTER, IntVar

root = Tk()

screen = Canvas(root, height = 430, width = 460)
screen.pack()

screen.create_text(200, 15, text = 'SUDOKU', font = 'calibri 20 bold')

screen.create_line(127, 54, 127, 408)
screen.create_line(232, 54, 232, 408)

screen.create_line(24, 170, 336, 170)
screen.create_line(24, 290, 336, 290)

check_button = Button(root, text = 'Check', font = 'Calibri 10 bold', bd = 0, bg = 'Green', fg = 'white', padx = 10, pady = 5)
screen.create_window(400, 70, window = check_button)

reset_button = Button(root, text = 'Reset', font = 'Calibri 10 bold', bd = 0, bg = 'Red', fg = 'white', padx = 10, pady = 5, command = reset)
screen.create_window(400, 110, window = reset_button)

x, y, n = 0, 0, 0

cols, rows, values = 9, 9, 81

col = [[None]*cols]*rows
val = [[IntVar]*cols]*rows

for i in range(0,rows,1):
    x = 0
    if i == 0:
        y += 70 
    else:
        y += 40
    for j in range(0,cols,1):
        x += 40
        col[i][j] = Entry(root, width = 2, font = 'Calibri 20', bd = 0, justify = CENTER)
        screen.create_window(x, y, window = col[i][j])
        x -= 5

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you construct col and val creates 9 rows pointing to the same 9 columns. Only one row is created then pointed to 9 times

```
cols, rows, values = 9, 9, 81
col = [[None]*cols]*rows
col
# [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]

col[0][1]=100
col
# [[None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
#  [None, 100, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Something like this should work.

```
col = []  # Empty lists
val =[]

for i in range(0,rows,1):
    x = 0
    if i == 0:
        y += 70 
    else:
        y += 40
    rowc = []  # Empty row lists
    rowv = []
    for j in range(0,cols,1):
        x += 40
        v = IntVar()
        ent = Entry(root, width = 2, textvariable=v, font = 'Calibri 20', bd = 0, justify = CENTER)
        screen.create_window(x, y, window = ent)
        rowc.append(ent)   # Append to the rows
        rowv.append(v)
        x -= 5
    col.append(rowc)  # Append rows to the column lists
    val.append(rowv)
```

Comment: Yes, I got it and now the functions are working properly thank you.